# How to apply a custom annotation to a List<String>?

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I created an annotation in order to validate the value of a String field (like an enum) :

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = GenericStringSetValidator.class)
public @interface ValidStringValue {

    String message() default "Must be a valid value. Found: ${validatedValue}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String[] values() default {};
}
```

And the GenericStringSetValidator used by the annotation :

```
public class GenericStringSetValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidStringValue, String> {

    private Set<String> validValues;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidStringValue constraint) {
            validValues = Arrays.stream(constraint.values())
                    .collect(toSet());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (value == null) return false;
        return validValues.contains(value);
    }
}
```

I already use this in the following class whithout any trouble :

```
public class SampleClass{
    private String id;
    @ValidStringValue(values = {"IN_PROGRESS", "COMPLETED", "DELETED"})
    private String status;
}
```

But I also want to use it in an other class with `List<String>` in order to validate each items of the `List`. Is it possible to configure my `ValidStringValue` interface to make it usable on a `String` and also a `List<String>` ?

```
public class SampleClassWithList{
    private String id;
    @ValidStringValue(values = {"A", "B", "C"})
    private List<String> sampleList;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Is `GenericStringSetValidator` your own `class`?

Comment: `GenericStringSetValidator` yes. I update my post to show it ;)

Comment: Seems like you just need to overload `isValid` by passing a `Collection<String>` and deciding the right logic (all need to be valid or one needs to be valid).

Comment: You could make your `GenericStringSetValidator ` implement `ConstraintValidator<ValidStringValue, Object>` instead. And then check with `instanceof` the different cases. Is it an array, a collection, a single value? etc

Comment: Thanks @Lino it works ! Indeed, it becomes a little bit dirty. I think the easiest maintainable solution is to create 2 differents validator one for `String ` and another for `List<String>` ;)

Comment: Is this Bean Validation (i.e. JSR 380)? Which version?

Comment: @Slaw yes it is. Why is it important ?

Comment: Because if you're using version 2.0 then you should be able to apply the annotation to the type argument: `List<@ValidStringValue(...) String> sampleList`. See [§5.5 Container element constraints](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-containerelementconstraints). Of course, your constraint annotation will have to be applicable to [`TYPE_USE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE_USE).